# Count survival to selection with functional programming

Tags: c++, c++11, functional-programming, refactoring

I would like to rewrite better my code using functional programming, but I am not so expert.

I have a collection of pointer to items:

```
std::vector<Item*>* collection;
```

I need to apply a selection to the items. The selection is made by several steps, everyone coded inside a function:

```
bool pass_step0(const Item& item);
```

For every step I need to know how many elements survive the selection. One element survive the selection if is pass the `and` of all the steps. So this is what I am doing

```
std::vector<int> nsurvivals_after_step;
std::vector<bool> mask(collection->size(), true);

int i = 0;
for (item : *collection) {
   if (not(pass_step0(*item)) { mask[i] = false; }
   ++i;
}
nsurvivals.append(count(mask.begin(), mask.end(), true));

i = 0;
for (item : *collection) {
   if (not(pass_step1(*item)) { mask[i] = false; }
   ++i;
}
nsurvivals.append(count(mask.begin(), mask.end(), true));
```

There are many repetition in the code and I have to use a global index `i`. How to use more sophisticated C++ feature to improve it?

Comment: I see nowhere in the code `&=`. What's your actual goal, what are you trying to accomplish by either `&=` or the code you provided?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit better:

```
std::vector<int> nsurvivals_after_step;
std::vector<bool> mask(collection->size(), true);

std::transform(collection->begin(), collection->end(), mask.begin(), mask.begin(),
               [](Item* i, bool m) { return m and pass_step0(*i); }
nsurvivals.append(count(mask.begin(), mask.end(), true));

std::transform(collection->begin(), collection->end(), mask.begin(), mask.begin(),
               [](Item* i, bool m) { return m and pass_step1(*i); }
nsurvivals.append(count(mask.begin(), mask.end(), true));
```

is it ok the way I am using `std::transform`? the third and fourth argument are the same!

Comment: If you're going to use `std::transform`, you'd want the `UnaryOperation` version... as is, your binary op is doing `m && pass_step0`, but `m` will always be `true` since that's what you initialized it to be. It's just extra code. Also don't use `and`, use `&&`.

Comment: No, `m` is always true only for the first `transform`. Why I should not use `and` ?

Answer (score 1):

You just want to count the number of items int he collection passing the filters? You could check out boost's [range adaptors](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/filtered.html):

```
using namespace boost::adaptors;

const Item& to_ref(const Item* item) { return *item; }

nsurvivals.push_back(size(*collection 
                          | transformed(to_ref)
                          | filtered(pass_step0)));
nsurvivals.push_back(size(*collection 
                          | transformed(to_ref)
                          | filtered(pass_step1)));
```

It's probably as clean as it gets. Plus, if you want to pass multiple steps, you can just keep the pipes going:

```
int passBoth = size(*collection 
                    | transformed(to_ref)
                    | filtered(pass_step0)
                    | filtered(pass_step1));
```

[Update] The pass* functions apparently take references, so added a `transformed`